# How to deny external access to a port in a pod deployed on kubernetes (eks)?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod on EKS running a process that listens to two different ports: 8080 and 8443. Only the 8443 port is exposed through a service but I noticed the 8080 can still be accessed using the podIP.
The 8080 port should only be reachable from inside the pod, how can I close it from all external access?

Comment: what you already tried?

Comment: @Vitalii I managed to do it at application level, but in my research a "network policy" seems to be a way to do it at kubernetes level

Comment: yes, first of all i also thought about exactly  "network policies", but I wasnt able to find proper solution exactly for your case